# Implementing random forest to predict the success rate and time of completion

Tags: r, survival, random-forest

I have a large dataset with more than 120 columns for which I'm trying to classify whether the order will be successful or not. There are two parameters that I need to figure out. One is the probability of survival for each row in the dataset, and the other is the time it'll take to reach the state of 0 or 1.

I am implementing random forest classifiers to predict the success rate, but not sure how to predict the time of completion. Can you please guide me to some resources that can be useful with this issue.

Edit: I guess it is more of trying to predict the individuals survival rate, giving an estimated number of days left until completion.

Comment: Take a look at randomForestSRC, which fits a random forest to the shape of the cumulative hazard and survivor curve.

Comment: But the survival curve gives an RoC like output giving a cumulative estimate. I was looking for a way to get the estimated time required to complete each order/row.

Comment: Well what does each row represent?

Comment: Each row is an order and we are trying to find if the order will close or not and by what time so as to get an estimate of the money flowing in.